# Mapping entries to a data frame column

Tags: r

Say I have a vector

```
vec1 <- c(4,8,2,9)
```

and another vector

```
vec2 <- c("One","One","One","One","Two",Two","Two","Three","Four","Four")
```

I'd like to get a data frame `myData` which looks like

```
V1    V2
4     "One"
4     "One"
4     "One"
4     "One"
8     "Two"
8     "Two"
8     "Two"
2     "Three"
9     "Four"
9     "Four"
```

Which means that `myData` has length(vec2) rows. If it helps: the data in vec2 is always arranged in a block - e.g. "One" can never occur in other rows that 1:4. Is there a method to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try using `match`:

```
data.frame(V1=vec1[match(vec2, unique(vec2))], V2=vec2, stringsAsFactors=F)

   # V1    V2
# 1   4   One
# 2   4   One
# 3   4   One
# 4   4   One
# 5   8   Two
# 6   8   Two
# 7   8   Two
# 8   2 Three
# 9   9  Four
# 10  9  Four
```

Another option using `rle`, thanks to @DavidArenburg:

```
data.frame(V1=rep(vec1, rle(vec2)$lengths), V2=vec2, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Or `cbind(V1 = rep(vec1, rle(vec2)$lengths), V2 = vec2)` in case `V2` is sorted like in the example.